# update the frontend label of an attribute in magento programmatically?

Tags: magento

I have an attribute with some attribute front end label.But I want to change frontendlabel for the product.Is there any function provided in magento to do this programmatically.

If yes,How can this be done???

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the more simpler solution to my question...

```
$attributeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attribute->setFrontendLabel($displayName)->save();
```

**setFrontendLabel(string $str)** is the function which best suits here.

Comment: You can actually just use the 3rd and 4th lines from your code  `$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attrributeId);
    $attribute->setFrontendLabel($displayName)->save();`

Answer (score 6):

The safest way to do that is to load the existing labels and then add your new store specific labels:

1 - retrieve the existing labels for all the stores

```
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getResource()
   ->getStoreLabelsByAttributeId($attributeId);
```

or

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$labels= $attribute->getStoreLabels();
```

2 - Add your custom labels

```
$labels[$storeId] = 'My new label for a specific store';

$attribute->setStoreLabels($labels)->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up frontend store labels for each store views, you can do it next way(This code for custemer attribute, but you can set frontend labels this way for all type of EAV-attributes.):

```
$installer->startSetup();

$attribute = array(
    'entity_type' => 'customer',
    'code' => 'customer_type_id',
    'translations' => array(
        'store_code_en_en' => 'english name',
        'store_code_at_de' => 'german name',
        'store_code_fr_fr' => 'franch name'
    )
);

$storeLabels = array();
foreach ($attribute['translations'] as $storeViewCode => $text) {
    $storeViewId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeViewCode, 'code')->getId();
    $storeLabels[$storeViewId] = $text;
}

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($attribute['entity_type'], $attribute['code']);
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute($attribute['entity_type'], $attributeId)
    ->setData('store_labels', $storeLabels)
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```